# Как проверить открыто окно или закрыто?

Tags: javascript

Как мне проверить открыта форма или закрыта на данный момент времени?
В функции *closed_form* я хочу написать условии: если форма открыта тогда то-то..
Попробовал обыграть с window.opener вышла фигня.

```
ButtonOpen.addEventListener('click', open_form); // Открытие формы
ButtonClosed.addEventListener('click', closed_form); // Закрытие формы
const openerWindow = window.opener;

function open_form() {
    BoxCenter.style.zIndex = 1;
    if (openerWindow) {
        console.info('Forma open');
    } else {
        console.info('Forma closed');
    }
};

function closed_form() {
    BoxCenter.style.zIndex = 0;
};
```

Дело в том, что я пытаюсь закрыть форму на серую область.
Всё работает круто! Но этот скрипт условие проверки "его нет тут" срабатывает даже на уже закрытой форме. Моя форма она является одним целым с основным DOM у меня нету дополнительного HTML файла. Поэтому мне нужно дополнительную проверку дописать.

Comment: Ну, сделайте переменную `const form_open = false;`. При открытии делаете `true`. Когда надо проверить смотрите эту переменную. Если хотите узнать когда она открыта, то сделайте переменную куда будете пихать время открытия.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. При чем здесь `window.opener`, и что такое "серая область"?

Comment: @Igor Когда форма открывается по центру экрана по бокам появляется затемнение, я назвал это серой областью.

Comment: @АлександрРогонов Мне так-же интересно узнать ваш метод. Скажите вы имели в виду сделать глобальную переменную? И в функции прописать эту-же переменную только со значением `true`? Я не очень понял этого

Comment: Ну вы написали, что хотите знать не только открыта форма или нет, но и когда она была открыта. Добавьте переменную, в самый верх `let formOpenTime = 0;` В момент открытия формы сделайте `formOpenTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);` в момент закрытия `formOpenTime = 0;`. Все, у вас есть переменная, к которой вы можете обратится в любой момент и узнать закрыто ли окно (formOpenTime === 0), а если открыто, то сколько секунд назад это открытие произошло.

Comment: @АлександрРогонов Оу нет, я не так написал или вы меня не правильно поняли. Время мне не нужно. Мне нужно вообще знать открыта форма или нет. Когда она будет открыта, тогда я в условиях это напишу, что вот теперь можно закрыть её. Извиняюсь за формулировку в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function closed_form() {
  if (BoxCenter.style.zIndex != 0) {
    BoxCenter.style.zIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Да спасибо вам Игорь можно и так проверить.. )
Я думал, есть какой-то универсальный метод. 
Допустим если-бы там не изменялось то самое значение z-index.. Тогда как?